# Insert formula into Excel with VBA and a dynamic range

Tags: excel, vba

I have some code that creates the formula I need and I used the macro recorder to autofill down to the last row. But how can I code it properly so that this is automatic and will fill the formula down to the last row of data? I am also trying to get rid of the select statements, just have not done that when trying to insert formulas yet.

```
Sub RD_DS_InsertCol_Formula()
'
' RD_DS_InsertCol Macro
'

    With Sheets("Raw Data - DS")
        .Columns("C:C").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    End With
    
    Range("G2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(RC[-1]=""Crossdock"",""CD"",IF(RC[-1]=""PickingPickedAtDestination"",""PP"",IF(RC[-1]=""PickingNotYetPickedPrioritized"",""PNYP"",IF(RC[-1]=""Loaded"",""LD,""""""))))"
    Range("G2").Select

    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("G2:G14665"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("G2:G14665").Select


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub RD_DS_InsertCol_Formula()
    With Sheets("Raw Data - DS")
        .Columns("C:C").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        .Range("G2:G" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row).FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(RC[-1]=""Crossdock"",""CD"",IF(RC[-1]=""PickingPickedAtDestination"",""PP"",IF(RC[-1]=""PickingNotYetPickedPrioritized"",""PNYP"",IF(RC[-1]=""Loaded"",""LD,""""""))))"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This placed the formula into cells G1 and G2, but none of the other rows in that column.

Comment: I modified your code to include: .Row + 1 after the .End(xlUp).Row + 1) and I got the Runtime 1004 error.

Comment: Which col can be used to determine the last data row?

Comment: A through F all have data to the last row. The number of rows will vary from day to day, but the columns will remain static.

Comment: Try `.Range("G2:G" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row)`